# R scripts execution on Apache

Tags: php, r, windows, apache

I have an PHP application which needs to pass parameters to a R script to be executed with PHP exec command.

Does anyone knows how to configure Apache Server and Windows 10 to allow the execution by the PHP exec command by the server?

r script

```
args = commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)

print(args[1])

print(args[2])

mainDir <- "C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\bot\\Rtry\\AruleInside\\data\\"

subDirFile <- args[1]

fileDownload <- args[2]

print(fileDownload)

destfiledownload <- paste(mainDir,args[1],"\\",args[2],".txt")

destfiledownload <- str_replace_all(destfiledownload," ","")


dir<- str_replace_all(paste(mainDir,args[1])," ","")

  if(dir.exists(dir))
  {
    download.file(fileDownload,destfiledownload)
  } else
  {
    dir.create (dir, showWarnings = TRUE, recursive = TRUE, mode = "0777")
    download.file(fileDownload,destfiledownload)
  }
```

php script:

```
$nmBot = "botTeste";        

echo('<div class="row" style="margin-top:5%; margin-bottom:5%;"><div class="col-md-12" style="text-align:justify;"><form role="form" style="margin:1%;padding:5%; border: 2px solid #2c64a4;border-radius:10px" 
                          action="'.htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]).'" method="POST">');
        
echo('<div class="form-group">   
  <label for="exemplo1">Exemplo1:</label>
  <input type="url" id="exemplo1" class="form-control" name="exemplo1"><br><br>');
                    
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
{       
    $ex1 = $_POST["exemplo1"];
    exec("Rscript C:\Apache24\htdocs\bot\Rtry\AruleInside\save.r ".$nmBot." ".$ex1, $out);
    exec("R CMD BATCH C:\Apache24\htdocs\bot\Rtry\AruleInside\save.r ".$nmBot." ".$ex1, $out);
}
```

I expect that the R script saves the content of the web page.

Comment: what problem are you having exactly when you try to execute a command? I don't think there's anything specific you need to enable, as such.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. You've made the requirement a little more specific, but it still doesn't indicate what problem you're having when you try to run the command, or where you've got stuck.

Comment: the problem is that it does nothing neither give me any reasonable output to solve the problem, the script i will put on the queston

Comment: Edit your question with an example of the command and the enclosing PHP code, the output you expect, and what you actually got as output instead.

Comment: Edited th output I expect is the creation of the directiory and dowload of the web content.

Comment: Thanks for the update. You have two exec() commands, and you don't seem to be checking the content of `$out` from either of them, to verify what actually happened when you executed them.

Comment: with var_dump and echo results ---------------------> array(3) { [0]=> string(14) "[1] "botTeste"" [1]=> string(32) "[1] "https://www.amazon.com.br/"" [2]=> string(32) "[1] "https://www.amazon.com.br/"" }
Warning: Array to string conversion in C:\Apache24\htdocs\bot\extraiRegras.php on line 64

Comment: did not help at all, maybe its an php issue? using php 8.19..

Comment: Yes that's a php error, you can google it to see what it means if you don't understand

Comment: no way changed php version didnot gave any new..

Comment: Why would changing the php version fix it, do you expect? You need to fix the actual error, by not trying to write an array directly into text output

Comment: sorry but you can see in var_dump the variables contents, if it was a php bug changing the version is a reasonable way to try to solve the problem, i shall ignore your last comment due to the help you tried to give me..

Comment: It's not a php bug though, php is issuing a warning about what your code is doing. I can't work out why you think it would be a php bug. So...which line is 64, in the code you've shown?